# Почему деструктор срабатывает несколько раз вначале, а не в конце?

Tags: c++, массивы, классы

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;

class vector
{
private:

    int *mass;
    int size;
public:

    vector(int *array, int n)
    {
        size = n;
        mass = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            mass[i] = array[i];
        }
    }

    int sum(vector B, int rez)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i=i+2)
        {
            rez = B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1]+rez;
        }

        return rez;

    }


    int vichitanie(vector B, int rez)
    {
        rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i = i + 2)
        {
            rez = (B.mass[i+1] - B.mass[i])+rez;
        }

        return  rez;


    }

    int multiple(vector B, int k, int rez)
    {
        rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            rez = (B.mass[i] * k)+rez;
        }

        return rez;

    }

    int modul(vector B, int rez)
    {
        rez = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            rez = pow(B.mass[i],2)+rez;
        }

        return rez;
    }


    ~vector()
    {
        cout << "Деструктор сработал" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{


    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int mass2[8];

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int p;
        cout << "Введите для 1 вектора " << i + 1 << " значение" << endl;
        cin >> p;
        mass2[i] = p;
    }

    int k, r = 0;
    cout << "Введите коеф." << endl;
    cin >> k;

    vector obj1(mass2, 8);
    //vector obj2(mass2, 8);

    obj1.sum(obj1,r);
    cout << "Сумма двух векторов = " << obj1.sum(obj1, r) << endl;

    obj1.vichitanie(obj1, r);
    cout << "Разность двух векторов = " << obj1.vichitanie(obj1, r) << endl;

    obj1.multiple(obj1, k, r);
    cout << "Умножение на коеф  = " << obj1.multiple(obj1, k, r) << endl;

    obj1.modul(obj1,r);
    cout << "Модуль вектора = " << obj1.modul(obj1, r) << endl;


    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: 1. Вы передавали vector как объект, а не по указатели / ссылке, из-за чего на каждый вызов метода создавалась копия вектора и после выполнения функции она удалялась. (т.к. была создана на стеке) 2. если методы вектора используются только для самого объекта, то и работайте с mass самого объекта

Comment: А за чем вы во всех этих функциях на вход передаете 'rez'? Такое ощущение что вы "зашли" в С++ с чего-то вроде VB. Вам бы сначала подучить мат.часть (указатели, вызовы функций и передача параметров), а потом уже изучать классы с их деструкторами. Извините, если что не так ;)

Comment: Ознакомьтесь на досуге о том, что такое [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Во всех предложениях вашей программы, аналогичных этим предложениям

```
obj1.sum(obj1,r);
         ^^^^
cout << "Сумма двух векторов = " << obj1.sum(obj1, r) << endl;
                                             ^^^^
```

создаются временные объекты класса `vector`, значения которых используются в качестве аргументов соответствующих методов, в данном случае метода `sum`

```
int sum(vector B, int rez)
        ^^^^^^^^
{

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i=i+2)
    {
        rez = B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1]+rez;
    }

    return rez;

}
```

После завершения работы метода эти временные объекты удаляются. Поэтому для каждого такого вызова метода соответственно будет вызываться деструктор для параметра метода.

При этом имеет место потенциальная утечка памяти, так как деструктор не удаляет созданный динамически массив `mass`. В деструкторе должно присутствовать предложение

```
delete [] mass;
```

Если вы включите это предложение в деструктор, как это требуется, то ваша программа будет иметь неопределенное поведение, так как один и тот же указатель будет удаляться дважды в виду того, что созданный компилятором неявно конструктор копирования просто создает копию указателя.

Поэтому вам надо в явном виде определить конструктор копирования и, возможно, копирующий оператор присваивания, если вы также собираетесь присваивать один объект класса другому, или определить его как удаленный.

Методы, подобные `mass` либо должны быть определены статическими, так как они не используют свойства объекта, для которого вызываются, и при этом передаваемый в качестве аргумента объект должен передаваться по константной ссылке, либо могут быть членами класса, но тогда в методах должен обрабатываться объект, для которого они вызываются.

Также все подобные методы имеют неопределенное поведение,  когда число элементов в массиве объекта равно 1, так как происходит обращение к несуществующему элементу с индексом 1.

```
rez = B.mass[i] + B.mass[i+1]+rez;
                         ^^^
```

Comment: Использовали статический анализатор? :)